# Extract string resource from string variable declared somewhere in class?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am getting my values in a random variable in a string here as cityname:-

```
 public static String cityName;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
        Log.v(TAG, longitude);
        String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
        Log.v(TAG, latitude);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I want to get the value coming to cityname as a string resource in xml,is it possible in some way?

Comment: Why you want to store cityname in Android string resource?

Comment: I want to use it as a default value in shared preferences,in shared preferences you need an integer resource value..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use cityname somewhere else in the app thats why you want to store it in string res file. So if you want to use the cityname somewhere else try to store it in sharedpreferences or in a file to use it later. Becoz its not possible to store strings dynamically in strings.xml file

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefs.edit().putString("defaultCityName", cityName).apply();
```

And to use this

```
public static String getPreferredLocation(Context context) { 
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   String defaultCityName = prefs.getString("defaultCityName","testCity");
   return prefs.getString(context.gettring(R.string.pref_location_key‌​}, defaultCityName); 
}
```

Comment: For which method of sharedpreference?

Comment: In this method i want to replace R.String.PREF_LOCATION_DEFAULTS with my string of cityname.


`public static String getPreferredLocation(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
                context.getString(R.string.pref_location_defaults));
    }`

Comment: you can send a string variable as a parameter as a default variable to prefs.getString() method. You can send your cityName variable as a default value but to access this cityName every where you need to store it somewhere. Make a prefs string for default cityName and store this cityName and send this as default value.

Comment: Can you explain to me how?I still can't figure out how can i use cityname which is a variable inside the prefs.getString as a default.How do i make pref string that uses the cityname variable?

Comment: As soon as you get cityName store it in sharedpreference like

Comment: As soon as you get cityName store it in sharedpreference like ~SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); prefs.edit().putString("defaultCityName", cityName).apply();~ and to use it as default value for others use it like this ~SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); ~

Comment: `String defaultCityName = prefs.getString("defaultCityName","testCity");  \nprefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.pref_location_key‌​), defaultCityName); `

Comment: if this worked for you then please mark the answer as correct